# Trace Downstream task: which ArcObject interface and method?

Tags: arcobjects, utility-network-analyst

Does anyone know what ArcObjects interface and method the Trace Downstream trace task on Arcmap's [Utility Network Analyst](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002r00000028000000.htm) toolbar calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `ITraceFlowSolverGEN` and the methods `FindFlowElements` or `FindFlowEndElements`, but I only guess that because of the ArcObjectsRoutines code found in the [9.3.1 NetworkTraceTask on the arcscripts site](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15238).

```
Dim pNewTrace As ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalysis.ITraceFlowSolverGEN
' ... some code, that constructs and sets up the solver '
   Case "TRACE DOWNSTREAM"
      If bTraceEnds Then
        pNewTrace.FindFlowEndElements(ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalysis.esriFlowMethod.esriFMDownstream, ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalysis.esriFlowElements.esriFEJunctionsAndEdges, pJuncEIDs, pEdgeEIDs)
      Else
        pNewTrace.FindFlowElements(ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalysis.esriFlowMethod.esriFMDownstream, ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalysis.esriFlowElements.esriFEJunctionsAndEdges, pJuncEIDs, pEdgeEIDs)
      End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.[IUtilityNetwork](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IUtilityNetwork_Interface/0025000009ww000000/) (or [IUtilityNetworkGEN](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IUtilityNetworkGEN_Interface/0025000009z1000000/) as appropriate).